# spark-shell from different users causes error

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I created and configured small hadoop cluster(1 master and 1 slave), and installed spark.

I used pre-buil `spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6` and `hadoop-2.7`.

When i run example

```
$ ./bin/spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi \
    --master yarn \
    --deploy-mode cluster \
    --driver-memory 4g \
    --executor-memory 2g \
    --executor-cores 1 \
    --queue thequeue \
    lib/spark-examples*.jar \
    10
```

from hduser (user that owns `/usr/local/hadoop`), all works fine, but when i try to run `bin/spark-shell` from same user following error occurs :

```
        Database Class Loader started - derby.database.classpath='' 16/03/02 16:55:32 ERROR Datastore.Schema:
 Failed initialising database. Cannot get a connection, pool error Could not create a validated object, cause:
 A read-only user or a user in a read-only database is not permitted to disable read-only mode on a connection. 
    org.datanucleus.exceptions.NucleusDataStoreException: Cannot get a connection, pool error Could not create a validated object, cause:
 A read-only user or a user in a read-only database is not permitted to disable read-only mode on a connection.
```

However, when i run `bin/spark-shell` from user: `user`, who owns `/usr/local/spark`, it works fine.

I have two questions:

First, is why this error happens in the first place?

Second, is what the best way to handle it? Perhaps make one user that owns both spark and hadoop? Or is it a bad practice?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why but what fixed this for me was first shutting down Zeppelin.  But then that produced the error you see above. So I rebooted the server.  It might be caused by using control-C to exit spark shell and leaving several users with a SparkContext going at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

This can be related to Derby, that try to write in a read-only filesystem.

A possible fix is to change the Derby database path, when submitting the application:

```
--conf "spark.driver.extraJavaOptions= -Dderby.system.home=/tmp"
```